# What are alternatives to Locks and critical sections in ZeroMQ (guide)

Tags: python-3.x, zeromq, latency, distributed-system, pyzmq

I am reading ZeroMQ-the guide, currently on Chapter 4, for those of you who know.

http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all

I am working in python with the binding pyzmq.

The author says that we should forget everything we know about concurrent programming, never use locks and critical sections etc.

Right now I am doing a pet project for fun with ZeroMQ, I have a piece of data, which is shared between some threads (don't worry my threads, don't pass sockets). They are sharing a single Database,

### ***my question*** is :

Should I put a lock around that piece of data, to avoid race conditions, like one normally would, in order to serialize access, or is this something to avoid when using ZeroMQ, because better alternatives exist?

I remember the author saying that one should always share data between threads using **`inproc://`** or **`ipc://`** ( for processes ), but I am not sure how that fits here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A lot of thrilling FUN in doing this, indeed

Yes, Pieter HINJENS does not advice any step outside of his Zen-of-Zero. Share nothing, lock nothing ... as you have noticed many times in his great book already.

What is the cornerstone of the problem -- **protecting** the **`[TIME]`**-domain consistent reflections of the Database-served pieces of data.

In [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system), the `[TIME]`-domain problem spans a non-singular landscape, so more problems spring out of the box.

If we know, there is no life-saving technology connected to the system ( regulatory + safety validations happily do not apply here ), there could be a few tricks to solve the game with ZeroMQ and without any imperative locks.

Use **`.setsockopt( { ZMQ.CONFLATE | ZMQ.IMMEDIATE }, 1 )`** infrastructure, with **`.setsockopt( ZMQ.AFFINITY, ... )`** and **`.setsockopt( ZMQ.TOS, ... )`** latency-tweaked hardware-infrastructure + O/S + kernel setups end-to-end, where possible.

A good point to notice is also that of the Python threading-model still goes under GIL-lock-stepping, so the principal collision-avoidance is already in-place.

---

### An indeed very hard-pet-project :
<sub>( ZeroMQ cannot and will not avoid problems )</sub>

**Either**
co-locate the decision-making process(es), so as to have an *almost*-zero latency on taking decisions on updated data,
**or**
permit a non-local decision taking, but make them equipped with some robust rules, based on latency of uncompensated <sub>( principally impossible until a Managed Quantum Entanglement API gets published and works indeed at our service )</sub> **`[TIME]`**-domain stamped event-notifications - thus having also a set of rules controlled chances to moderate DB data-reflection's consistency corner cases, where any "earlier"-served DB-**`READ`** has been delivered "near" or "after" a known DB-**`WRITE`** has changed its value - both visible to the remote-observer at an *almost*-the-same time.

Database's own data-consistency is maintained by the DBMS-engine per se. No need to care here.

Let's imagine the Database-accesses being mediated "through" ZeroMQ communication tools. The risk is not in the performance-scaling, where ZeroMQ enjoys an *almost*-linear scaling, the problem is in the said `[TIME]`-domain consistency of the served "answer" anywhere "behind" the DBMS-engine's perimeter, the more once we got into the [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) realms.

Why?

A DBMS-engine's "locally" data-consistent "answer" to a read-request, served by the DBMS-engine right at a moment of `UTC:000,000,000.000 000 000 [s]` will undergo a transport-class specific journey, along the intended distribution path, but -- due to principal reasons -- does not get delivered onto a "remote"-platform until `UTC:000,000,000.??? ??? ??? [s]` ( depending on the respective transport-class and intermediating platforms' workloads ).

Next, there may be and will be an additional principal inducted latency, caused from workloads of otherwise uncoordinated processes requests, principally concurrent in their respective appearance, that get later somehow aligned into a pure-serial queue, be it due to the ZeroMQ **`Context()`**'s job or someone else's one. Dynamics of queue-management and resources-(un-)availability during these phases add another layer of latency-uncertainties.

Put together, one may ( and ought ) fight as a herd of lions for any shaving-off of the latency costs alongside the { up | down }-the-paths, yet getting a minimum + predictable latency is more a wish, than any easily achievable low hanging fruit.

DB-**`READ`**-s may seem to be principally easy to serve, as they might appear as lock-free and un-orchestrated among themselves, yet the very first DB-**`WRITE`**-request may some of the already scheduled "answer"-s, that were not yet sent out onto the wire ( and each such piece of data ought have got updated / replaced by a DBMS-local **`[TIME]`**-domain " ***freshmost*** " piece of data --- **As no one is willing to dog-fight, the less to further receive shots from a plane, that was already known to have been shot down a few moments ago, is she ... ?** )

These were lectures already learnt during collecting pieces of [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) smart designs' experience ( Real Time Multiplayer / Massive Ops SIMs being the best of the best ).

**`inproc://`** transport-class is the best tool for co-located decision taking, yet will not help you in this in Python-based ecosystems ( ref. GIL-lock-stepping has enforced a pure-serial execution and latency of GIL-release goes ~3~5 orders of magnitude above the *almost*-"direct"-RAM-read/write-s.

**`ipc://`** transport-class sockets may span inter-process communications co-located on the same host, yet if one side goes in python, still the GIL-lock-stepping will "chop" your efforts of minimising the accumulated latencies as regular blocking will appear in GIL-interval steps and added latency-jitter is the worst thing a Real-Time [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) designer is dreaming about :o)

Comment: Thank you for the insanely detailed answer, as always.
i love python, but this is the first time someone gave me a solid enough reason not to love it :( .
But what if i went multi process over multi threads, is that feasible to solve the GIL issue ? 

i appreciate your efforts for answering my question, but i am still not very good at programming and definitely not ZMQ but from i am able to understand, you are suggesting that we need not enforce a lock on DBMS and have some rules that ensure that our data is not super out of date.

Comment: Great to read you have considered the Answer helpful, the more an " *insanely detailed* ". Pleasure to hear that. StackOverflow encourages users to click **[ +1 ]** on interesting or inspiring Answers, so feel free to do so and **[ Accept ]**. If interested in more questions, do not hesitate to open 'em - this is the way StackOverflow works.